# model_to_dict raise AttributeError when set lazy_load to False for ForeignKeyField in Peewee

Tags: python, flask, peewee

I'm using Peewee for my flask project.

Codes are as following.

```py
# model
class Release(Model):
    created_at = DateTimeField()
    project = ForeignKeyField(Project, backref='releases', lazy_load=False)

# ...

# controller
class ProjectReleaseController(Resource):

    def get(self, project_id, release_id):
        record = Release.get_or_none(Release.id == release_id)
        logger.info(f'{record}')
        return jsonify(model_to_dict(record))

# ...
api.add_resource(ProjectReleaseController, '/projects/<project_id>/releases/<release_id>')
```

When send `GET:/projects/1/releases/2` to the server, `model_to_dict` will raise error

```
    field_data = model_to_dict(
    ...
    for field in model._meta.sorted_fields:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

And `logger.info(f'{record})` output `2`. (??? why ???)

If I change `lazy_load=True` (default value) as following

```py
project = ForeignKeyField(Project, backref='releases', lazy_load=True)
```

Then it will return the right value.

```json
{
  "created_at":"2021-06-29T18:56:28.718841",
  "id":2,
  "project":
    {
      ''' quite many things '''
    }
}
```

The questions are:

1. how to understand it behave so different with `lazy_load` to `False` or `True`.
2. When `lazy_load=True`, how to get rid of the project information in response by simply give me `project_id: 1`.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here what I found out.

`model_to_dict ()` accepts a parameter `recurse` to indicate if foreign-keys should be recursed. You can find it in the [document](https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#shortcuts).

```py
user = User.create(username='charlie')
model_to_dict(user, recurse=False)
```

In this case, the project information mentioned above won't be recursed.